# What does : mean in a script in package.json?

Tags: angular

Here I have 2 scripts from a quickstart project in Angular2. What does `:` mean in `server:dev`?

```
"start": "npm run server:dev",
"start:hmr": "npm run server:hmr"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the name of the property in the scripts object in package.json has a colon in it.

```
"scripts": {
  "server:dev": "echo \"Running server:dev\" && exit 0"
},
```

Comment: Can we use server_dev instead?

Comment: @benone: yeah but it might [not be a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47606101/what-is-colon-in-npm-script-names#comment110362761_47606101).